# I created a tab on the ribbon of outlook ,now i want to retrieve the tab from that ribbon programatically using redemption laibrary

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I have created windows Application in Visual studio and created a ribbon in outlook. All that is fine now I have to iterate the tabs from ribbon and find the created tab and again iterate inside the tab to find particular button. All this retrieval has to be done with redemption library. Can you please help me how to do it?

Comment: It that wen i click on a particular button it should internally iterate through the ribbon to find the required tab . I am not getting how to iterate using redemption library. I have imported the reference-- Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object library ..anything else i have to import?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Redemption doesn't provide anything for that, nor the Fluent UI. What is the final goal?

You may try to use [Accessibility API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the job done.

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Using Outlook Add-in I have created Ribbon and Tab called "MY TAB" inside that tab i have a button called "CONNECT". Now i have one Windows Form application on click of certain button from the Form it should internally iterate through  ribbon to find "MY TAB" .This could be done by redemption right?

Comment: Why do you need to look for ribbon controls? What exactly do you want to reach in Outlook? Run it progrmmatically?

Comment: I have to Run through each of the Outlook toolbars and locate toolbar ‘MY TAB’ using Redemption Library.

Comment: Yes i have to do this by the action of click of button on the windows form application.

Comment: Why do you need to look for a button on the ribbon? What is your goal?

Comment: I have to connect to different application so my goal in the project is to iterate through toolbars and locate the Button "Connect" if it is there means it is not connected to the application if it not there means already connected. If found it should automatically take the action of click on to button to connect to different application. That is the goal